# Need to remove values from an ArrayList in C#

Tags: c#, arraylist

So I have been asked to remove tour codes that **end** with the letter G, GE, G=, or Z. The only bad thing is I believe we use this call for a lot of pages and that is the reason I cant alter the database call in the first place so I want to do this specifically for this one person. My code is calling an arrayList that fills with all the tourcodes we have. Is there any way I can remove the tours with the letters above. Here is what I got to work with.

```
public void LoadTourCodes()
{
    ddlTourCode.Items.Clear();

    if (ddlTourCode.Visible)
    {
        ddlTourCode.Items.Add(new ListItem(" ", ""));

        ArrayList tourCodes;
        tourCodes = EblTipTours.FindTourCodes();

        foreach (string tourCode in tourCodes)
        {                   
            ddlTourCode.Items.Add(tourCode);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using LINQ, like this:

```
var toRemove = new []{"G", "GE", "G=", "Z"};
foreach (string tourCode in tourCodes.Where(code => !toRemove.Any(suffix => code.EndsWith(suffix)))) {
    ddlTourCode.Items.Add(tourCode);
}
```

If you cannot use LINQ because it's a legacy system, you can rewrite the code like this:

```
string[] toRemove = new string[] {"G", "GE", "G=", "Z"};
foreach (string tourCode in tourCodes) {
    bool good = true;
    foreach (string suffix in toRemove) {
        if (tourCode.EndsWith(suffix)) {
            good = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!good) continue;
    ddlTourCode.Items.Add(tourCode);
}
```

Comment: Yes we arent using LINQ and it looks as if the second part worked to perfection!! Thank you so much for the help and I understand what you are doing with the flags much easier then removing just not add it. Perfect!!